# Char array filling with blanks

Tags: array, loop, keypad, char

When I run this code, my `pin` and `pinCheck` arrays are not being filled with the results of `keypad.getKey()`. If I print the value at each index, the result is blank. As far as I can tell, I am either not writing a char to the array, I am misreading the array when it comes time to print to the serial monitor, or `.getKey()` only works in the main or loop functions.

```
#include <Key.h>
#include <Keypad.h>

void armDisarm(void);
boolean array_cmp(char, char, int, int);

bool isArmed = 0;
char pin[3];
char pinCheck[3];
const byte ROWS = 4; // number of rows
const byte COLS = 4; // number of columns
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
{'1','2','3','A'},
{'4','5','6','B'},
{'7','8','9','C'},
{'#','0','*','D'}
};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {9, 8, 7, 6}; // row pinouts of the keypad R1 = D8, R2 = D7, R3 = D6, R4 = D5
byte colPins[COLS] = {5, 4, 3, 2};    // column pinouts of the keypad C1 = D4, C2 = D3, C3 = D2
Keypad keypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);
 
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
 
void loop()
{
  if (isArmed == 1)
  {
    Serial.println("SYSTEM ARMED! ENTER PIN TO DISARM!");
  }
  else 
  {
    Serial.println("SYSTEM DISARMED! ENTER PIN TO ARM!");
  }
  armDisarm();
}

void armDisarm(void)
{
  while(true)
 {
    if (isArmed == 0)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < 4;)
      {
        if (keypad.getKey() == NO_KEY)
        {
          continue;
        }
        pin[i] = keypad.getKey();
        Serial.println(pin[i]);
        i++;
      }
      isArmed = 1;
      return;
    }
    else if (isArmed == 1)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < 4;)
      {
        if (keypad.getKey() == NO_KEY)
        {
          continue;
        }
        pinCheck[j] = keypad.getKey();
        Serial.println(pin[j]);
        j++;
      }
      for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
      {
        if(pinCheck[k] != pin[k])
        {
          isSame = 0;
          break;
        }
        else
        {
          isSame = 1;
        }
      }

      if (array_cmp(pin, pinCheck, sizeof(pin), sizeof(pinCheck)) == 1)
      {
        Serial.println("same pin"); //used for bebugging
        isArmed = 0;
        return;
      }
      else
      {
        Serial.println("INCORRECT PIN! CLAYMORE ROOMBA DEPLOYED!");
      }
    }
  }
}

boolean array_cmp(char a[sizeof(pin)], char b[sizeof(pinCheck)], int len_a, int len_b)
{
  int n;

  // if their lengths are different, return false
  if (len_a != len_b)
  {
    return false;
  }

  // test each element to be the same. if not, return false
  for (n = 0 ;n < len_a; n++) 
  {
    if (a[n]!= b[n])
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  //ok, if we have not returned yet, they are equal :)
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is one essential feature of the Keypad library you
have to understand: it is non-blocking. When you call `keypad.getKey()`,
it returns immediately, and almost always returns `NO_KEY` to signal
that no key was pressed since the last time you checked. If a key was
pressed, `keypad.getKey()` returns that key and then, *on the next
call*, it again returns `NO_KEY` because no key was pressed *since the
last time you checked*.

It is important to realize that, whenever a key is pressed, that key is
returned *only once* by `keypad.getKey()`. You should manage to not miss
it!

Now consider this loop:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 4;)
{
    if (keypad.getKey() == NO_KEY)
    {
        continue;
    }
    pin[i] = keypad.getKey();
    Serial.println(pin[i]);
    i++;
}
```

This will run very fast, and almost always looping through the
`continue` statement. When a key is pressed, `keypad.getKey()` returns a
value different from `NO_KEY` (and this value *is lost*), the test
within the `if` is false, and the statement that follows gets executed,
namely:

```cpp
    pin[i] = keypad.getKey();
```

But this is *another* call to `keypad.getKey()`, which returns `NO_KEY`,
so this is what gets saved in the array.

This is how I would write that loop:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    char key = NO_KEY;
    while (key == NO_KEY)
    {
        key = keypad.getKey();
    }
    pin[i] = key;
    Serial.println(pin[i]);
}
```

Please note that:

- The value returned by `keypad.getKey()` is *always* saved into a
  variable, you do not want to loose it! When we get something other
  than `NO_KEY`, the value previously saved into the variable is stored
  in the array.
- I moved the `i++` where it belongs, in order to avoid that very
  confusing way of controlling the loop.
- The `if` has become a `while`, because we do not want to move to the
  next iteration until we have actually read a valid key.
- The loop does only three iterations, because this is the length of the
  array `pin`, which we would otherwise overflow.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition ToEdgar Bonets answer. I should warn you that your code keeps adding position in as each time you check array you are increasing the value of i. As a result you are filling arrays with NO_KEY.

Also having have build a security alarm on arduino before (Or shouldnt we know thats what you are doing?) I should warn you that waiting for Keyboard inputs mean that you are not checking tamper or alarm even when its armed because you are stucked inside nonloop function waiting for imput.
I have personally made input a global struct

```
struct foo{
   char digits[4];
   byte digit=0;
} pinCode;
```

You can either take instance of the struct as a parameter to your function or because its global use it internaly.

```
bool addDigit(char button){
  /*here deal with many potential inputs*/
```

you can then inside your function assign the button pressed as

```
pinCode.digits[pinCode.digit]=button;
pinCode.digit++;
```

if you are passing the instance of the struct as a pointer then it will change to

```
pinCode->digits[pinCode->digit]=button;
pinCode->digit++;
```

you can then inside this funtion test if password is confirmed (OK is pressed) and return true.

While the end of the password isn't reached, just return false.
SO within the loop you would have something like:

```
key = keypad.getKey();
if(key!=NO_KEY){
   if(addDigit(key)) //Here take an action based on inputs
}
// Do all the other stuff alarm has to do
```